AzureDevops API: Image not uploaded
I use the method
POST
"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?uploadType=Simple&fileName={filename}&api-version=5.0"
headers
headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Size": str(os.path.getsize(file_path)),
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
}

I get a successful response and a link to the image, but the image is 'broken', white square instead of original image


Hi #Steph, Have you got a chance to test my script in my answer below to upload attachment image with binary content? Hope it can resolve your issue in this post. Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Thank you, I accepted the answer

We can call this API first to upload the attachment image with binary file content and then sent this request to add the uploaded file as an attachment of a work item.
Here is the sample Python script for your reference which works from my side.
import base64
import json
import requests

# Define your Azure DevOps organization, project, and personal access token
organization = "YourADOOrgName"
project = "TheProjectName"
personal_access_token = 'XXXXXX'

# Encode the personal access token in base64
base64_pat = base64.b64encode(f':{personal_access_token}'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')

# Define the path to your image file
image_file_path = "C:/Users/Alvin/Desktop/testImage.png"

# Read the binary contents of the image file
with open(image_file_path, "rb") as image_file:
    image_file_bytes = image_file.read()

# Define the URL for uploading the attachment
upload_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=testImage.png&uploadType=Simple&api-version=7.1-preview.3"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Basic {base64_pat}",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
}

# Make the API request to upload the binary file
response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=image_file_bytes)
upload_response = response.json()

# Get the attachment URL from the upload response
attachment_url = upload_response['url']

# Define the URL for updating the work item
work_item_id = 2308
wit_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{work_item_id}?api-version=7.1-preview.3"

# Define the body for the work item update request
attachment_body = [
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "AttachedFile",
            "url": attachment_url,
            "attributes": {
                "comment": "Add a test image attachment from Python script"
            }
        }
    }
]

# Make the API request to update the work item
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json-patch+json"
response = requests.patch(wit_url, headers=headers, json=attachment_body)
update_response = response.json()

# Print the response of the work item update request
print(json.dumps(update_response, indent=4))


